# Make a dictionary out of values on a json file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I need to get two values from different objects of this json file and make a dict with them, summing the int values. I am getting the first value like this :

```
for d in data:
    for (date, details) in d['nightlyDetails'].items():
        for (key, value) in details.items():
            if key == 'accountLabelType':
                print(key,value)
```

but I want to make a dictionary that makes a set with `defaultdict` so to have only one for each of the key names and then the total sumed values. How do I get `totalRent` values and sum them, then make a dict with only one key of each and the values sumed ?

This is how the json file looks :

```
"checkOut": "2016-02-04",
  "sourceBusinessName": "xxxx.com",
  "folioStatusIdUserDef": "0",
  "discounts": 0,
  "reservationDate": "2015-06-30 07:13:11",
  "additionalGuestIds": [],
  "lastNightAuditDate": "0000-00-00",
  "adjustmentTotal": 0,
  "totalRent": 1280,
  "noOfSplits": 1,
  "checkoutDate": "2016-02-04 10:19:30",
  "noOfNights": 1,
  "folioNo": "44108",
  "pm_code": "",
  "arrivalAmpm": "am",
  "folioStatus": "Checked-Out",
  "checkinBy": "xxxx",
  "reservedBy": "Oboe Reservation",
  "event_training_id": "0",
  "housekeepingRuleId": "0",
  "occupancyAdults": "2",
  "nightlyDetails": {
    "2016-02-03": {
      "accountLabelId": 1,
      "accountCategoryId": 6,
      "NightlyOverrideType": "0",
      "accountCategoryType": "Add-on",
      "NightlyRoomTransferId": "0",
      "accountLabelType": " Rooms \u74e6\u5382\u623f\u95f4",
      "NightlyRateId": "196",
      "NightlyActualPrice": "1280.000000",
      "NightlydiscountType": "0",
      "NightlyOverride": "0.000000",
      "rateName": "SQ",
      "NightAuditDate": "0000-00-00",
      "NightlyPaidByGroup": "0",
      "NightlyOfferedPrice": "1280.000000",
      "Nightlydiscount": "0.00",
      "NightlyActualDiscountPrice": 1280
    }
```

What I actually need is a dict like this :

```
Homes:10000
Rooms:3500
```

So, a dict that contains only one of each of the `accountLabelType`, and the sum of all the `totalRent` values for each type. This json is just a demo, as it is very long. It repeats many times, as many as room bookings there are.

Comment: Did you try `json.load(json_file)`? Or do you need to do more than just open the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have already parsed the JSON files to a list of dictionaries `data`. I summed up the `totalRent` values for each `accountLabelType` in a `dict`:

```
totalRent_dict = {}

for d in data:
    accountLabelType = None
    for (date, details) in d['nightlyDetails'].items():
        for (key, value) in details.items():
            if key == 'accountLabelType':
                accountLabelType = value
    if accountLabelType:
        try:
            totalRent_dict[accountLabelType] += d['totalRent']
        except KeyError:
            totalRent_dict[accountLabelType] = d['totalRent']
```

Comment: check my edit at the end of the question, sorry for being unclear

Comment: I edited my question. I don't understand what kind of dictionary you want to generate that has `Homes` and `Rooms` though. This code just checks the `accountLabelType`, and sums up the `totalRent` values for each `accountLabelType`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [the Python `JSON` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html?highlight=json).

```
import json

Dict = json.load(open(file_name))
```

Then `Dict` will be a dictionary.

Comment: Seems like he already has done that and the title of the question just isn't what he really is asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what your asking but...

```
from operator import itemgetter
ig = itemgetter('totalRent')
rents = map(ig, data)
totalRent = sum(rents)
```

This is how you can get the sum of the `totalRent` values from the whole `data` `dict`.

I didn't quite get why you would want a `defaultdict` there.
Except if you're gonna extract more of the values other than `totalRent`.

You might wanna be a bit more precise on what you actually want out of the data.
Like give us a sample dictionary of what the output should look like.

Comment: check my edit at the end of the question, sorry for being unclear

Answer (score -1):

You can use [object_hook](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#module-json) to transform the dict into an object and then perform all the operations using that object. It will be easy to handle and gives a more cleaner approach then manipulating dict directly for your complex operations.

> object_hook is an optional function that will be called with the result of any object literal decoded (a dict). The return value of object_hook will be used instead of the dict.

Also take a look at object_pairs_hook.